# How to get camel exchange in cxf interceptor

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I want to get the exchange body in cxf interceptor and make it as a camel exchange property. So that I can use this property in any processor or bean methods.
I tried to get exchange with 
`message.getExchange()`
but it will return a cxf exchange. How can I use the `org.apache.cxf.message.Message` to get the `org.apache.camel.Exchange`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you cannot do it exact that way because CXF interceptors are beyond Camel and have no idea about Camel. Camel Exchange is above CXF.
 But if you need to do exact what you said:

> get the exchange body ... and make it as a camel exchange property

What does prevent you from doing that in the processor at very first step in Camel route? Why do you try to do that in CXF Interceptor?